"The Best Regex Trick" in Raku
The Best Regex Trick is about writing regexes that match r1 but not r2. The example they give is a regex that matches Tarzan (and "Tarzan and Jane") but not "Tarzan". After going through some things that don't work, they give the "best regex trick ever":
"Tarzan"|(Tarzan)

This supposedly matches the "bad string" first, skipping the good string, but not including the bad string in a capture group. If only the good string appears, we match on it last and include it in the capture group.
One downside of the "best regex trick" is that this still matches "Tarzan", even if it doesn't capture it. You can't eg use it in a conditional without some extra boilerplate?
This is based on PCRE-style regexes. Raku uses an entirely different regex notation. Is it possible to do the trick more simply? Ideally this should be possible:
> ('"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"') <<~~>> /some-regex/
(Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣)


I'm not familiar with regular expressions in Raku, but the best regex trick is explicitly about discarding the straight matches, only looking at the first group match. So, you should do that. I'd be very surprised if Raku doesn't have a facilty for examining only groups. Even a non-best regex like /prefix-(\d+)/ (to extract digits that start with "prefix-") is an oft used construct. It is handled exactly the same as the best regex trick - bin the regular match, only look at the group.

Direct equivalent of "The Best Regex Trick"
say (« '"Tarzan"' Tarzan '"Tarzan and Jane"' » «~~» /'"Tarzan"' | (Tarzan)/)»[0]

# (Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣)

Discussion of the code, reading from right to left:

What is [0]? A list "subscript". It's a reference to the zeroth element of the list on its left. Unlike in older regex dialects, in Raku, positional captures are numbered from zero, not one. So the captures associated with the (Tarzan) positional sub-capture in the regex are stored as positional sub-capture zero of an overall match instead of positional sub-capture one.

What is »[0]? A hyperoperation. For our purposes here it's like running a traditional map function that, for each element on the left (which will be an overall regex match of one of the strings on the far left), yields the zeroth positional sub-element (which will be the zeroth, i.e. first, positional sub capture).

Why have I written '"Tarzan"' in the regex instead of "Tarzan"? Unlike in older regex dialects, _in Raku, code of the form "foo" in a regex represents the three character string foo, not the five character string "foo". One way to represent the latter is to write '"foo"'.

What is «~~»? Another hyperoperation, like the postfix/unary »[0] one described above, but this time an infix/binary one with operands on both sides. (The original question included the same hyperoperation.)

What is « '"Tarzan"' Tarzan '"Tarzan and Jane"' »? A list of strings. Raku has a family of list-of-strings constructors; « ... » in term position (as against operator position) is its "word" quoting with quote protection list constructor.




is it possible to do the trick more simply?

A step that's arguably in the right direction is:
say « '"Tarzan"' Tarzan '"Tarzan and Jane"' » «~~» / '"Tarzan"' <()> | <(Tarzan)> /

# (｢｣ ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣)

Notes:

<(...)> explicitly delimits the top level capture, narrowing it from the default top level capture (which captures everything that matches).
<()> means the top level capture is empty. That's not Nil, but could suffice depending on your needs.
<(Tarzan)> specifies the top level capture (in contrast to (Tarzan) which specifies the first sub-capture).


The original specification for Raku regexes included some relevant features that have not yet been implemented. It's possible they may one day be implemented and provide a simpler solution.

See also @tshiono's answer.

See also @alatennaub's excellent answer on reddit.

Tangent: I like « … » most of the time, but I'm not a fan of it here. Yes, it saves 4 characters, but it results in a list of 3 strings, two of which are quoted and one of which isn't – which breaks the "similar things should look similar" rule and draws attention to the list's second item. And, since there's nothing special going on there, that's just a distraction. But TIMTOWTDI, and that's just my ¢2.

<( and )> don't need to be paired. So if we're okay returning ｢｣, you can simplify your solution to say « '"Tarzan"' Tarzan '"Tarzan and Jane"' » «~~» / '"Tarzan"' <(|| Tarzan / ).

@codesections Great minds think alike!  I've upvoted your comments to convey support for them. ✅ But I've not altered my answer because the rationale that led to the code I published still applies. [ FWIW I too thought the things you've mentioned; early iterations of the list of input strings part of my code included using (...) (and [...]) before choosing to use «...», despite seeing what you see; early iterations of the regex part used just <( for controlling the top level capture, and || instead of | as the alternation op, before choosing <()> and |. ]

As you mention, Raku uses an entirely different regex notation. Would you please try:
> ('"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"') <<~~>> / <!after \">Tarzan | Tarzan<!before \"> /

Result:
(Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣)


<!after \"> denotes the negative lookbehind assertion.
<!before \"> denotes the negative lookahead assertion.
The double quote character must be escaped.
The alternation | may be surrounded by whitespaces.


Very informative and nice answer, cheers.


Ideally this should be possible:
> ('"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"') <<~~>> /some-regex/ 
(Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣) 


Is this close enough?
> (('"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"') <<~~>> / '"Tarzan"' || ('Tarzan') /)»[0] 
(Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣) 

Or, slightly clearer IMO:
> (['"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"'] «~~» / '"Tarzan"' || ('Tarzan') /)»[0] 
(Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣) 

Or if you're going to be using the "extract first capture from a match" idiom all the time, you could even define the composition of ~~ and [0] as a new operator (here, ~~[0]
my &infix:<~~[0]> = *[0] ∘ &[~~]; 
('"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"') «~~[0]» / '"Tarzan"' || ('Tarzan') /;
# Returns (Nil ｢Tarzan｣ ｢Tarzan｣) 

But that's probably overkill! (And also has to be on one line in the REPL due to a bug).
(All of this builds on @alatennaub's excellent reddit answer  that @raiph already mentioned. Check that answer out for ways to avoid matching `"Tarzan"' at all, which avoids the need to select the first capture)

As always I learned a lot from @raiph and this answer is a small refinement on his with hopefully a bit more space:
my @tests = [ '"Tarzan"', 'Tarzan', '"Tarzan and Jane"' ];

my regex reg { 
    '"' ~ '"' 'Tarzan'              # non-capturing
    |                               # otherwise
    ('Tarzan')                      # capturing with ()  
} 
 
say .<reg>[0] for ( @tests «~~» /<reg>/ );

Notes:

personally I was a bit confused with the « ... » term quoting
it feels cleaner to define the @tests and regex separately
I like @alatennaub's room to breathe & copious comments
I use the ~ tilde for balancing match of both "


I suspected the « ... » quoting would be confusing for most readers, but was confident that the OP would understand them and likely appreciate my decision to use them. I love the separation into @tests and regex (I did that too in an early version of my code), and the room to breathe, and copious comments, in @alatennaub's post and yours.

The text matching '"' ~ '"' 'Tarzan' would be captured. Thus say ( @tests «~~» /<reg>/ )[0].<reg>; # ｢"Tarzan"｣. Given that the topic here is The Best Regex Trick, which is about focusing attention on sub captures (which don't include the ｢"Tarzan"｣), rather than the overall capture (which does), the # non-capturing when double quoted comment strikes me as unfortunate.

well it would be if you placed capturing parens() around that alternate - but, in the wake of the other examples,  there are only capturing parens () around the other alternate and why I need [0] to destructure at the end - I vaguely see the use of <()> to capture at the top level, but have yet to get my head around that

SWNW¹, either your logic is off, or your language is off. Unless a regex² specifies otherwise, all text matched by a regex is captured. What you have called "capturing parens ()" do indeed capture, but capture a substring of the overall capture. That's why your code refers to .<reg>[0] not .<reg> (the latter refers to the overall "top level" capture). ‡ ¹ SWNW = Socratic Wonder Not Withstanding. I won't claim knowledge other than that my language ("either X or Y") is off, but we must abbreviate in comments!  ² A regex (eg /.*?/) is more than just a regex pattern (eg .*?).
